# The enigmatic indent element video

Tags: html, css, video

I can not understand the origin of the indent tag video, where the block with class сontrols. I need to get this unit was down, and he jumps out of bounds. And how else can you align the unit with the class progress-bar-wrapper?

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
<video id="movie">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="movie.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>
<div class="controls">
    <button class="play-pause">Play</button>
    <span class="progress-bar-wrapper">
        <span class="progress-bar"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="display-status"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

Here's a link to the sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/gztmcyxg/

Comment: Not sure why this happens, but you can float the button and the progress bar to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/gztmcyxg/3/

```
video {
    vertical-align: top; //or middle
}
```

The default one (baseline) causes that spacing. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

That issue can be annoying. Usually it happens when an object has a inline-block display. I'm not sure why it's happening in this instance.

One way of resolving that is setting the font-size to 0 in the wrapper:

```
.video-wrapper {
    font-size: 0;
}
.controls {
    /* be sure to reset the font-size for your controls */
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gztmcyxg/2/